# Monotonicity of Ratio of Bessel Functions

Tags: bessel-functions, monotone-functions

Let $$g(x)=\frac{xK_{n-1}(x)}{K_{n}(x)}$$ I want to prove that this function is increasing in $(0,+\infty)$ $\forall n=0,1,2\dots$. I tried to directly derive and using the recursion properties of $K_n$ but I had no luck. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is shown in Theorem $6$ of [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00025-021-01531-1) that for any $\nu\geq 0$, the function
$$
(0,+\infty) \ni x \mapsto \frac{{xK'_\nu  (x)}}{{K_\nu  (x)}}
$$
is strictly decreasing. Then for all $\nu\geq 0$, the function
$$
(0,+\infty) \ni x \mapsto \frac{{xK_{\nu  - 1} (x)}}{{K_\nu  (x)}} \equiv  - \nu  - \frac{{xK'_\nu  (x)}}{{K_\nu  (x)}}
$$
is strictly increasing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and reference.

Comment: It seems to me that this is valid also for negative $\nu$. Right?